# Chrome Developer mode のコンソールから AngularJS の関数を直接呼べるか

Tags: angularjs

Javascript 初心者です。

とある Web アプリケーション上の所定の操作を自動化してみようと思いました。
このページにはボタンがあり、その html 要素は、

```
<a class="btn" ng-click="somefunc()">
  somefunc
</a>
```

となっていました。

このボタンをクリックした際に呼ばれる javascript を、 chrome の developer console から実行したいのですが、これを実現する方法はありますか。 console 上で

```
> somefunc()
```

と実行しても、そのような関数は定義されていない、というエラーが返ってきています。

質問:

- どうやったら、上記の somefunc() を developer mode console から実行できますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

細部がわかりませんが、
onclickにイベントが登録されているのは間違いないと思えるので
例えば
`document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0].click()`
（`0` は該当エレメントのクラスでコレクションを得た時の位置。）
で、実行できると思います。

Comment: 該当 node を getElement して、 click() を呼べば確かに実行できました。